# "can't find ns" when trying to get the distance for all records from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using this query in Robomongo/cli to get the records which are nearest to the given co-ordinate which is working correctly.

Below is my query using **find**

```
db.places.find(
  {
    loc : {
      $near : {
        $geometry : { 
          type : "Point" , 
          coordinates : [12.974729, 77.609375]  
        }, 
        $maxDistance : 2000
      }
    }
  }
);
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c6becd8586e7a757260d62"),
    "name" : "address here",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            12.9802900000000001, 
            77.5857400000000013
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d002a7ce57e202b2cd43ea"),
    "name" : "address 2",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            12.9751499999999993, 
            77.6248930000000001
        ]
    }
}
```

Now how do i get the even the distance. I using the below query but gives me **errmsg** has **"can't find ns"**

```
db.runCommand( {
    geoNear: "places" ,
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [12.974729, 77.609375] },
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: 2000
})
```

Comment: Why are you issuing the `runCommand`? Why not just the `find()` with `$nearSphere`? That is the correct operation for a spherical distance. Is there a `"2dsphere"` index on `"loc"` or not? Because you need one. And also you should not have more than one `"2d"` or `"2dsphere"` index on a collection. It's often pointless, and it confuses commands like `"geoNear"` or aggregation `"$geoNear"` which presume there is only one index.

Comment: Hello Blakes, yes i have created **2dsphere** index. But how to get even the distance for each and every record using nearSphere,  like how runCommand gives the **dis** distance object as a response

Comment: '"geoNear"` or `"$geoNear"` will return the distance if that is what you want. But your error seems to indicate either no index or too many indexes. That's the first thing you need to fix